# Android studio on windows using google maps

Tags: android, windows, google-maps, android-studio

I have

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

In my build.gradle Module: app
and

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="true" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml in between the application tag.

Yet still I get an error on import

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
```

and a similair error on

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
```

and other such imports.

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'maps'
```

I tried cleaning the build, invalidate cache/restarting neither worked.

I read somewhere that it was an issue with a conflict between android maps and google maps and that you need to use:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:21"
```

But that gives me an error too

```
Error:Could not normalize path for file 'C:\Users\...\app\build\intermediates\mockable-Google Inc.:Google APIs:21.jar'.
```

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

According to a little search that is because it is trying to make a folder with the :  symbol that works on mac/linux but not on windows.

I can change it to

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
```

But then it doesn't use the google api's. And I haven't found another way to fix my code. Anyone that can help me out or point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Changing the play-service to 5.+ (or anything below) gives me a different error, namely that it appears to overwrite a theme.

```
C:...\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\5.0.89\res\values\wallet_colors.xml
Error:(1) Attribute "theme" has already been defined
```

And anything 6 or above means it cannot find LocationClient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try with this configuration in your manifest :

```
  <!-- Creating Permission to receive Google Maps -->

    <permission
        android:name="com.yelpmeout.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.yelpmeout.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>



........



  <!-- Google Maps Fragment API Key Data -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR_KEY" /> // dont forget to add your key
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="YOUR_ACTIVITY" /> // dont forget to add your main activity here
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"  />
```

And this in your gradle :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

}
```

It works  for me, it should also work for you.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Alas that did not solve my issue. I still get cannot resolve LocationClient en maps from


import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;



import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint; (and other maps.*;

Comment: Did you set up the playservice correctly ? [http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html] (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) . Did you try to rebuild your project once the modification in your build.gradle done ?  


Otherwise, try this : 

Go to project properties, and go to Android. Select "Google API" instead of Android x.x. Rebuild your project and now it should work.

@RekijanKileren

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing:

```
<uses-library
    android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml. Try adding it and see if it works.

Comment: I have already included that in my AndroidManifest (like it says in my second code block).